# Why is mysql_num_rows() returning 0?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have read in another threads that pasting the query in phpMyAdmin returns the amount of rows that you have, but in my case it doesn't even returns a value in phpMyAdmin, it's always 0! Here is the query:

```
$query = "SELECT nom_usu FROM usuarios WHERE nom_usu = '$usu' AND pass = '$pass';";
```

I open the .php file and run the query and it returns empty values, like this:

```
SELECT nom_usu FROM usuarios WHERE nom_usu = '' AND pass = '';
```

I also tried to echo the value that returns and is, guess what? Zero!

Here is the complete .php file (is for a login):

```
<?php

    include('dbConfig.php');

    $usu = $_POST["usu"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];

    $query = "SELECT nom_usu FROM usuarios WHERE nom_usu = '$usu' AND pass = '$pass';";

    echo $query."\n";

    if($resultado = mysql_query($query)){
      if(mysql_num_rows($resultado) > 0){
         echo mysql_num_rows($resultado);
         echo "Todo est&aacute; bien, no te preocupes :)";
         echo true;
      } else {
         echo mysql_num_rows($resultado);
         echo "Hay algo mal aqu&iacute; :(";
      }
    } else {
     echo false;
    }

?>
```

And the dbConfig.php file:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$user="neosoftw_lambda";
$contra="myPass"; <- This is not actually my password...
$db="neosoftw_lambdaMovil";

$ms = mysql_connect($host, $user, $contra) or die("No se pudo conectar :(");
mysql_select_db($db, $ms) or die ("No hay base de datos :(");   

?>
```

Hope someone can help me figure out where I have gone wrong?

Here is what I want to make, is a login in jQuery Mobile, but it doesn't work!

Username: bryan
Password: azul

http://android.neosoftware.org.mx/

**Edit**

Maybe it could be because of my javascript?

```
$.post("http://android.neosoftware.org.mx/PHP/login.php", {usu : usu, pass : pass}, function(respuesta_login){

            if(!($("#txt_usuario").val() || $("#txt_password") == '')){
                $.mobile.changePage("#campos_vacios");
            } else {
                if(respuesta_login == 1){
                    $("#txt_usuario").val('');
                    $("#txt_password").val('');
                    $.mobile.changePage("#pag_principal");
                } else {
                    $.mobile.changePage("#error_login");
                }
            }


        });
```

Comment: Can you post your database structure with data? Also, sql injection .. blah blah blah.

Comment: Your POST values are not there, simple as that. What is the output of `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: Are you aware that you cannot ordinarily send values using AJAX to a different domain? `android.neosoftware.org.mx/PHP/login.php` is that the same domain as your javascript one?

Comment: Yes, I'm using that domain to send the values in the login form

Comment: I mean to ask whether your login form also resides on android.neosoftware.org.mx ? and what are the values of your usu and pass javascript variables?

Comment: Yes, it does, you can check it out in the link I have put in the question, the domain I'm using for the login.php is the same domain I'm using for the login form.

Comment: The values of 'usu' and 'pass' in my javascript code have the value of the text input in the login form.

Comment: Don't store passwords. Ever. Stop what you're doing until you have addressed this. It won't matter if it works, it won't achieve the actual goal of secure authentication. Don't build an authentication script until you are more familiar with proper password handling. You are putting all users and their passwords at risk. People entrust in you when supplying their password. Stop.

Comment: http://phpsec.org/articles/2005/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
$query = "SELECT `nom_usu` FROM usuarios WHERE `nom_usu` = '".$usu."' AND `pass` = '".$pass."'";
```

Also this type of problem occurre when `$_POST` variable is empty.. So, double check your code.

**Note :** `mysql_*` function is deprecated, move on `mysqli_*` function asap.

Comment: What is different in this query, functionally, from OP's query except back ticks? how is this supposed to solve it?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky did you checked my whole query? you can't see any other update?

Comment: Nope I cannot see any other update. Those extra quotation marks are not a must and your query will produce 100% same result as their query did. Interpolation works fine in double quotes. Their problem is that those variables do not hold a value.

Comment: that depends on the structure of code. sometime without double quotes php variable remains same (0). I faced this many times, and sometime it works.. :)

Comment: Impossible. if  `$usu = $_POST["usu"];` doesn't give a value to $usu in double quotes then the only reason is that it was not set in POST. Programming is not guess work, it either works or it doesn't work. This will work 1 million out of 1 million times. There is no `depends` or `sometimes` in this case :)

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky yes that is also possible :)

Comment: That is the `only thing possible` here. Since I've said so much, I will not retract my down vote just so that you don't feel that I'm against it, I just don't agree with this answer.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky no issue on upvote-downvote, main thing is the accurate answer, and thanks for pointing me. If you can't point, I never see my mistake. I always learn from the mistakes.

Comment: In my comment above I meant to say `now retract`, and I mistakenly wrote `not retract`. I have retracted my downvote

Comment: And from what I can tell they are functionally identical. Sorry homes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli` or `PDO` statements, as `mysql` is deprecated. Try this:

```
 $usu = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["usu"]);
 $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["pass"]);

 $query = "SELECT nom_usu FROM usuarios WHERE nom_usu = '".$usu."' AND pass = '".$pass."'";
```

And also your condition is incorrect.It should be like this:

```
if($resultado == mysqli_query($query)){
```

Comment: It didn't work, any other idea of what it could be? I don't understand what's wrong with it! The variables are empty in the query, and I'm sending the correct fields and the jQuery application always send me to the "Incorrect information" dialog!

Comment: Your POST values are not there, simple as that. What is the output of `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Yes so that means check your FORM that posts to this PHP, your PHP is fine